# NextJS if statement wrapped a .map

Tags: reactjs, next.js

**I am wondering how do I wrap my if statement to include the .map function.**

Basically, if they have been featured in a video I want it to say Featured On: and then show the videos.

```
{
  data.directory.videos ? <h2>Featured On:</h2> : <></>;
}
{
  data.directory.videos.map((video, i) => {
    return (
      <Col lg="6">
        <Vyt id={video} height="200" />
      </Col>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there a property to indicate "featured?"

Comment: Just if data.directory.videos is not NULL or undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to put your `map` inside some JSX conditioned off of the truthiness of `data.directory.videos`:

```
{
  data.directory.videos && (
    <>
      <h2>Featured On:</h2>
      {data.directory.videos.map((video, i) => {
        return (
          <Col key={video} lg="6">
            <Vyt id={video} height="200" />
          </Col>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Note: I am assuming here `video` can be used as the `key` for your `Col` component, but adjust accordingly.

Comment: That worked but just needed to remove the ; from the ); and it worked fine Thanks